# Passing additional context variables with HTTP requests in generic.ListView

Tags: python-3.x, django-views

I returned a rendering request in a specific function, and after that the variables stored in the get_context_data function stopped working. I want all variables to work ({{ ads_type_values }}, {{ results }}, {{ submitbutton  }}. Could you show me the best way to show all the variables on the same page?

```
class Buy(generic.ListView):
 #some code

  def gety(self,request):
     #skipped code
     context = {'results': results,'submitbutton': submitbutton}
     return render(request, 'ads/buy.html', context)


    def get(self, request):
        return self.gety(request)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Buy, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ads_type_values'] = Ads.ADS_TYPES
        #[..more variables here ..]
        return context
```